# trying to build a web ui tree from scratch

Tags: javascript, html, tree

I have seen yahoo ui using div for every node of the tree. Is this a good thing to do. Seems like every node including leaf node is heavily nested. I saw a div, table, tr, td being used for creating a node. Is this necessary. Is there a better way to do the same.

I tried to us tr for every node. Are there any issues with this approach

Thanks

Comment: Using canvas would make this a whole lot easier...  I tried doing this with divs at the end of last summer and... IE just wouldn't cooperate.  If you want to connect divs together with a line [connecting parent and child graphically] that's a pain too...

Answer (score 1):

Try this: [Pure CSS Tree](http://www.thecssninja.com/css/css-tree-menu)